# Using Python regex find words starting and ending with specific letters

Tags: python, regex

I don't use or do much text searching but have not been able to find an answer as to what the regex is to find all words starting with T and ending with T from a text file where each word is on a newline. Tried a number of suggestions from searches; the following finds all words starting with T and where T occurs next. However, I want to find where the LAST letter is T also, irrespective of how many T's occur between. Apologies if this is actually trivial, but after every combo I can find I have no result. I am unsure why `r'^T.*T$'` doesn't work.

```
with open('/Users/../words.txt') as f:
    passage = f.read()
words = re.findall(r'T.+T', passage)
print(words)
```

Comment: @DeepSpace, ok I ruled out TT, but if you like german cars that could match something :)

Comment: You are reading the whole file into memory? Ok, so you need `words = re.findall(r'(?m)^T.+T$', passage)` - use `^` and `$` and make them match start/end of a *line* with `(?m)` modifier.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for showing me how to fix what I understood was the problem, namely matching to the line.

Comment: I don't understand why downvotes occur for legitimate questions. Grrr.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use that expression:

```
re.findall(r"\bT\w*?T\b",s))
```

- use word boundary
- use any numbers of `\w` to avoid matching spaces in between
- use "non-greedy" mode (maybe not that useful here since word boundary already does the job)

Comment: Thanks -- \bT.*T\b also seems to work. Thanks for this answer; I suspect the ^...$ combo gets tripped on the line returns, as noted in the comments.

Comment: No, the `.*` will skip over any non-word characters.  It seems to work if you have a single word per line, but the posted solution is much more general.

Answer (score 2):

Use word boundary anchor `\b` and non-whitespace character `\S`:

```
words = re.findall(r'\bT\S+T\b', passage)
```

this will also allow to match such words as `Trust-TesT`, `Tough&FasT` etc.